# Stylesheets are not loaded in a modular JavaFX Application published as PKG

Tags: css, javafx, modularity, java-module

I have a modular JavaFX application. It perfectly loads all stylesheets when I run it using the IDE IntelliJ.

However, when I publish the application as PKG for Mac platform and try to run, no CSS is applied to the application. The PKG file successfully installs the JavaFX application on Mac but no stylesheet is loaded.

The app run as expected but without any CSS applied.

I am using openJDK-15.0.2 and generating the PKG file using jpackage.
Folder Structure:

[image: Folder structure]

To get the resources:

```
Class clazz = SocketClientFX.class;        
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.getStylesheets().add(clazz.getResource("/styles/Styles.css").toString());
```

Comment: Does it work if you run it as a jar file? What is the resource lookup you are using for the CSS file?

Comment: Hey @James_D, I have updated the post to better explain the situation. I have tested only with the PKG generated by jpackage. I did not try with a single jar file. The app runs correctly after installing the PKG file, but no CSS is applied.

Comment: Check that the CSS is deployed, and is in the expected location. If you navigate to the application in terminal, and go to the `Contents` and then app folder, you should see the jar file there. You can list the contents with `jar -tf myJarFile.jar`.

Comment: I have only the SocketClientFX.cfg file in the app folder. I couldn't find the jar file in the Content folder. But the app runs.

Comment: Ah, maybe because it is modular your actual application is effectively bundled as part of the JVM. Dig around in the `runtime` folder...? My best guess here is that the CSS is not being deployed somehow, but that's not the only possibility.

Comment: There appears to be an undocumented Java tool named `jimage`, at least with my Windows distribution I got from Liberica. You can try and use `jimage list path-to-image/runtime/modules` (or whatever the path is to your "modules" file) to inspect the contents of the image.

Comment: A better command might be `jimage list --include **.css <path-to-modules-image>`.

Comment: @James_D, thanks. But I couldn't find any jar in runtime folder as well. Yep, I also think the CSS is not being deployed.

Comment: @Slaw, what do you mean by <path-to-modules-image>?

Comment: The run-time image includes a "modules" file, at least on Windows (located at `<java-home>/lib/modules`). I assume there's the same or similar file on Mac. When building a custom run-time image that's where all modules go. Search the image created by `jlink` / `jpackage` for that file and then point `jimage` at it.

Comment: @Slaw, I found the modules file and executed the command "jimage list --include **.css modules". And the command found the css file I'm trying to load. "Module: socketclientfx
    styles/Styles.css". So, it seems that is being deployed. But I still do not understand why it is not loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding "**opens**" in **module-info.java** for each resource folder.

For example:

```
opens styles.common;
opens jsonFiles;
opens images.common;
opens styles.stevePane;
etc...
```

In the code, each resource is accessed as follows:

```
containerBorderPane.getStylesheets().add("/styles/stevePane/loadingWindow.css");
```

Then I built the project again and create a new PKG file. When I installed and run it again, all resources including the CSS files were loaded.

When the resource is accessed via getResource(), as below, we do not need to add `opens directive` in the `module-info.java`.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(clazz.getResource("/styles/Styles.css").toString());
```

Thank you, @James_D and @Slaw, for your comments.

Comment: Interesting. Since you're using `getResource(...).toString()` I would not expect you to need to add `opens` directives. Usually accessing resources via an absolute URL it "bypasses" the module system's encapsulation.

Comment: @Slaw, you are totally right. I've update the answer to explain your comments. I was testing two projects that make reference to the resources using different approaches (with and without getResource()) and I didn't mention that in the answer. In the end, one of the projects needed to use opens and the other don't (the project that uses getResource). Thank you again for your observation.